# How can I fix the oledbexception: Undefined function 'convert' in expression?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am attempting to insert a single record into an SQL Server 2012 database, programmatically, using a small VB.net application.  When I execute the application, the following OleDBException is caught:

> Undefined function 'convert' in expression

My VB looks like this:

```
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connstring)
    Dim comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(insertcommand)
    comm.Connection = conn

    Try
        conn.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        txbErrorSummary.Text += ex.ToString()
    End Try
```

Where insertcommand looks like:

```
INSERT INTO XXX([JCN], [DOT]) 
VALUES('PD7654',convert(varchar, '2/17/2014', 101))
```

Interestingly, when I cut and paste the insertcommand into the SQL Management Studio, it inserts the record with no trouble.  Thoughts?
Appreciate the help

Comment: Why are you using an OleDbConnection instead of SqlConnection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to do this other way. Instead of trying to run convert inside SQL, do this in .NET application and pass already `DateTime`m object.

The probelm with `convert` function is that it is not an OleDB valid function. If you use SqlCommand it will probably works correctly, because this function is T-SQL valid only for MS SQL

Comment: Thanks a bunch. +1 to Steve.  He hit on it but I didn't catch on that its not an OleDB function.  I used oledb because I read in from an access db and was inserting into an sql server db.  I didn't think to switch the connection type on the insert.  all is well, thanks Garath/Steve